# Compiling curl with http3 - stuck on step with ngtcp2

Tags: curl, openssl, http

I'm trying to compile curl with the experimental http3/quic stack. I've read and followed cookbook examples in a couple of places (most specifically here(https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/HTTP3.md)) without success.

I'm currently stuck on with the ultimate compilation of curl being stuck trying to find several ngtcp2_crypto_* functions.  I believe that I've traced this back to a problem with the ngtcp2 compilation missing a "--with-openssl" flag in the configure step. When I run that I get an error:

```
checking for OPENSSL... yes
checking for SSL_is_quic... no
configure: openssl does not have QUIC interface, disabling it
configure: error: openssl was requested (--with-openssl) but not found
```

However, the version of openssl I have installed, which is the version with QUIC enabled, is able to successfully connect to Google as follows:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_3
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = Google Trust Services LLC, CN = GTS Root R1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I have the SSL libraries installed with quic extentions
OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Do you have openssl libraries installed? This is different from the `openssl` program. What is your OS? Please {edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: replied in original question.

Comment: Please add more details what exactly you installed and how/where, the exact `configure` command(s) you use and the output of `type openssl`. Maybe the configuration finds some openssl developer library in a system directory. Then you might have to specify where to find your manually installed version with QUIC support.